# Show dynamic cell color for range coming from servlet in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make a simple web application based on Inventory management system. My question is as below,

I am fetching product data from database to a servlet which includes it's quantity.And I want to show that data in my JSP in a tabular format.I also want to change the cell color of quantity dynamically based on some threshold value.like .. if my threshold is 50 then

if quantity < 49 then cell color should be Red

if quantity > 51 then cell color should be Blue

if quantity is 50,49 or 51 then cell color should be Green.

How to implement that code ??

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read how the JSP EL works? WHat's the difficulty?

Comment: Use switch/case statement

Answer (score 1):

First define those colors in sane CSS style classes.

```css
.understock {
    color: red;
}
.normal { 
    color: green;
}
.overstock {
    color: blue;
}
```

Then just let JSP generate the desired style class.

```
<table>
  <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
    <tr>
      <td class="${product.quantity < 49 ? 'understock' : product.quantity < 51 ? 'normal' : 'overstock'}">${product.quantity}</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with Javascript I'll use AJAX to get the information from the Database.
http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php

I would suggest you to use PHP instead of Javascript though. Javascript developming for making that is quite more complex and not required.

That's the information you need in order to get information from the database.
http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Once you got the information it's just PHP

```
    if($value < 50){
     echo '<tr><td style="background-color:red;">text of the cell</td></tr>';
    }elseif($value == 50,49 OR $value == 51){
echo '<tr><td style="background-color:blue;">text of the cell</td></tr>';
}elseif($value > 51){
echo '<tr><td style="background-color:blue;">text of the cell</td></tr>';
}
```

You can also do this code above with *switch* function.

Comment: This is not really [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Plus, OP is using JSP, not PHP.